# Exists $f \in I(X)$ such that $f(u)$, $f(v)$ nonzero.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$ be algebraic, and let $u$, $v \in \mathbb{A}^n - X$. Prove that there exists $f \in I(X)$ with $f(u) \neq 0$ and $f(v) \neq 0$.

Comment: I suppose that you have some ideas on how to deal with this problem. Could you share them with us?

Comment: Since the bell has been rung, it probably doesn't hurt to point out this question on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/219498/exists-f-in-ix-such-that-fx-neq-0-fy-neq-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $u \notin X$ there is $f_1 \in I(X)$ satisfying $f_1(u) \neq 0$. If $f_1(v) \neq 0$, then we are done, otherwise $f_1(v) = 0$. Similarly, since $v \notin X$, there is $f_2 \in I(X)$ satisfying $f_2(v) \neq 0$. If $f_2(u) \neq 0$, we are done, otherwise $f_2(u) = 0$. Now$$(f_1 + f_2)(v) = f_2(v) \neq 0,\text{ }(f_1 + f_2)(u) = f_1(u) \neq 0.$$So setting $f = f_1 + f_2$, and since $I(X)$ is an ideal, $f \in I(X)$, we are done.

Answer (score 2):

As $u \in \def\A{\mathbf A}\A^n -X$, there is $g \in I(X)$ with $g(u) \ne 0$, if moreover $g(v) \ne 0$, we are done with $f = g$. Otherwise, choose $h \in I(X)$ with $h(v) \ne 0$, if moreover $h(u) = 0$, we are done with $f = h$. Otherwise, set $f = g+h$.